# PHP Best Practice - Read GET/POST parameter multiple times or create variable

Tags: php, variables, url-parameters

I was wondering what's actually the best practice in this case. Which of the following code snippets would you use?

```
doStuff($_GET["param"]);
doMoreStuff($_GET["param"]);
```

or

```
$variable = $_GET["param"];

doStuff($variable);
doMoreStuff($variable);
```

Is there any difference in the aspect of performance or even just in how a good PHP code should look like?

In case that the first one would be better, at how much function calls would you recommend to use a variable?

Comment: as soon as GET and POST variables have to be sanitized before processing, you have to sanitize it, and then to assign to variable, as it will be used in different places. Variable assignment doesn't affect performance really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should filter parameters in global variable `$_GET`. So best practice is store filtered data from `$_GET` in variable and use it in other parts of code. Filtering is good approach, because it makes your code more secure.

There you can read about filtering input: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: There is no reason why you cannot filter $_GET/$_POST array occurances back into the $_GET/$_POST array

Answer (score 0):

Your code would generate warning if $_GET["param"] is not set.

I would first verify that `$_GET['param']` actually exists, and then do whatever you like.

```
if(!isset($_GET['param'])){
    //fail here with exit() or exception, or whatever
}

//your code here, now you know for sure that $_GET['param'] is present
doStuff($_GET['param']); //or whatever you like
```

You should also further verify you param accordingly, if its integer check for `is_numeric()`, and better do casting after `(int)`. `empty()` is also your friend here, but be aware that if `$_GET['param']="0"` `empty()` will return true.

After verification is done you can choose either method, both are fine. Ultimately it will depend on the situation you are in.

Comment: If the parameter is not set $_GET['param'] give you null and no warning

Comment: do whatever logic you have planned, issue warning to user, or whatever you want to do.

Comment: @PrototypeX7 You obviously run with `display_errors = Off` and never look as the PHP Error log. Doing a `$var = $_GET['param'];` when `$_GET['param']` does not exist in the `$_GET` array generates a `Notice: Undefined index: param`

Comment: Just by the way, your post doesn't really answered my question. I was specifically asking, which of my code snippets are better, or if multiple cases exists, how I should use them. I didn't asked about how I can prevent errors, if the parameter is not set.

Comment: You should definitely look in your PHP error log. Notices like that are not a good practice, since we are talking about good practices here. Production code should be run with `display_errors` off. BTW, my post answered your question, because at the end I said - your both methods are fine.

Comment: @MuhammedM. _Production code should be run with display_ errors off_ Yes, but only after it has been tested with `display_errors On`

Answer (score 0):

Both are practically the same;

```
$variable = $_GET["param"];
```

Will clean your style up and will be more useful if you're using using the same variables in different pages.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the $_GET array is also a variable. Therefore, using $_GET multiple times shouldn't be a problem. When you create a seperate variable for the GET data, your script will need more memory.

When you are doing the same stuff several times (for example filtering something out of a user's input), it is considered best practice to create a variable for this and don't manipulate the $_GET or $_POST array. In my opinion, it is confusing if you expect the direct user input in the $_GET array, but it contains filtered/manipulated data.

Comment: And there is no reason why you cannot sanitize $_GET/$_POST data back into the array occurance it came from.

Comment: Sure, you can do that. However, in my opinion, it is confusing if you expect the direct user input in the $_GET array, but it contains already filtered/manipulated data. Moreover, if you use functions like http_build_query(), they rely on the contents of the $_GET variable and expect the user input inside.

Comment: But if you leave the filtered data in $_POST/$_GET it documents what data you are using in every line of code you write that does use it.